# Compass Sass Framework Sprite Path and Layout setting (SASS/CSS)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using Sass & Compass Framework for compiling my CSS. I am working in my local environment. When I dealing with the Compass Sprite image generation, I am encountering two different problems.

1. I want to set the layout to horizontal or smart or anything other than default vertical but I could not. I checked the syntax and I am using the right one, folder name plus the layout, but could not get it to work. All other setting like gap, spacing, all work.
2. I currently do not have a server running. I need a relative path from my css folder to image folder. Something like this "../images/xxx.png". Compass is all using the absolute file path based on my config file. Is there anyway that I could set setting to use relative path instead of absolute path? I tried the URL helper mixin which also generate the absolute path.

I am great appreciated for all the helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For the #2 use `relative_assets = true` in your config file.

If your aren't already I also suggest you use the [stylesheet-url and image-url Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/) functions that calculate automatically the path to your configured image and css folders, from where you call them.
If you call `image-url(myfile.jpg)` from a .css file in your css folder, it will compile to `url(../images/myfile.jpg)`.

Comment: I tested the answer for 2nd question. It works. Add something on top of it, background: image-url("main/css.png") no-repeat  config file defined the image path to the images folder, main folder is the folder inside the images folder. and the path needs to wrap in the quotation mark.